# Can we deliver HEIF images through a CDN?

Tags: ios, media, hevc, heif

I'd like to deliver HEIF images through a CDN such as Amazon CloudFront after release iOS11.

But we can't use Nokia's HEIF implementation for commercial purposes because of [this license](https://github.com/nokiatech/heif/wiki/VI.-License).
So I'm looking for an another method to encode HEIF images.

Accordig to [Introducing HEIF and HEVC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/?time=1977), HEIF images can only be created by iOS devices that have A10 Fusion chip.

> we currently only have HEIF encode support and hardware on iOS with minimum configuration being the A10 Fusion chip, an example, of which, is the iPhone 7 and the iPhone 7 Plus.

Can we deliver HEIF images that are created by iPhone7 etc through a CDN?
Is this a patent infringement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964) You may be able to get help on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), but [**read their faq carefully** before proceeding](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is only talking about hardware-level encoding support. HEIF is a format developed by MPEG and isn't Apple-controlled. Usability and support are still limited, but AFAIK there aren't any technical or legal reasons why you *cant* use it anywhere (if supported):

More information and links to C++ and JS libraries here:  https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/

Comment: As the original post states, Nokia's implementation cannot be used for commercial purposes. Their license explicitly states that it may only be used for non-commercial purposes.

Comment: @Cutterpillow that's good to be clear on, but that's about those specific libraries. The format itself isn't affected.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ: HEIF was developed by Nokia. What the Moving Picture Experts Group (MPEG) developed is h.265/HEVC, which is the preferred algorithm used to compress image data which is then encapsulated by HEIC.

As with many formats, creating a HEIF/HEIC file is essentially a two-step process. First the image data is compressed, then it is packaged. Apple's hardware encoder almost certainly only performs the first step, whereas the second step would be performed in software. This is important here because Nokia's reference implementation only performs that second step, and not the first.

Comment: @rspeed I believe you're somewhat misinformed. Neither HEIF or HEVC was created by a single entity. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding. The intensive part is the (currently) HEVC encoded image and/or video that HEIF wraps. This can be done in software or hardware, but is rather expensive to do in software with generic computing. After than the HEIF wrapper is (relatively) trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing issue you're concerned about is *only* for Nokia's reference implementation. My guess is that Apple is using their own implementation. Regardless, it's not something you need to be concerned about.

If for some reason you are looking to create HEIF images yourself, there's at least one open-source implementation currently available for commercial use. Specifically, [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/2017/06/09/gpac-support-for-heif/). Though its license (LGPL) does have its own set of potential drawbacks for commercial projects.